# What would prevent php-fpm (8.0.16) from being able to write to an NFS mounted filesystem?

Tags: php, nfs, fpm

I have a php-fpm (8.0.16) instance that cannot write files to an NFS share. I am using a simple php script for testing:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

$fp = fopen('test.txt', 'a');

fwrite($fp, 'test');
```

When running via php-fpm, in a directory that is an NFS share, the following error is received:

> Warning: fopen(test.txt): Failed to open stream: Read-only file system in /path/to/nfs/share/test-write.php

However, the following code:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

$fp = fopen('/tmp/test.txt', 'a');

fwrite($fp, 'test');
```

works as expected.

The script works when run from the command line as the same user that is used to run php-fpm both in an directory on an NFS share, and in /tmp.
Additionally, the script works as expected on earlier versions of php via php-fpm.

Comment: [sf] might be a better place to ask this.

Comment: Are you auto-mounting the NFS share?

Comment: There's nothing innate to PHP that would cause a failure here, this is a system configuration issue.

Comment: And read-only filesystems are system-wide, not per-process. I don't see how it could get that error from php-fpm but not get it when you run the script in the same directory by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the systemd php-fpm.service file there was a setting:

```
# Mounts the /usr, /boot, and /etc directories read-only for processes invoked by this unit.
ProtectSystem=full
```

This is what was preventing php-fpm from being able to write to the NFS share as it was mounted in a subdirectory of /usr.

As mentioned [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/996397/failed-to-open-stream-read-only-file-system-when-trying-to-create-file-outsid) you can override this using `systemctl edit php-fpm.service` and adding paths that need write access:

```
[Service]
ReadWritePaths=\path\that\needs\write\access
```